No mappings found when path includes extension
I am trying to map a health check but I keep getting a 404 for it. The mapping file looks like:
{
  "Priority": 200,
  "Request": {
    "Path": {
      "Matchers": [
        {
          "Name": "ExactMatcher",
          "Pattern": "/z_adds_mat_info.asmx"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Params": [
      {
        "Name": "op",
        "Matchers": [
          {
            "Name": "ExactMatcher",
            "Pattern": "Z_ADDS_MAT_INFO"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Methods": [ "POST" ],
    "Body": {
      "Matcher": {
        "Name": "XPathMatcher",
        "Pattern": "//item[*]/CORRID[contains(text(),'HEALTHCHECK')]"
      }
    }
  },
  "Response": {
    "StatusCode": 200
  }
}

with a body that looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Z_ADDS_MAT_INFO xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <IM_MATINFO xmlns="">
    <CORRID>HEALTHCHECK</CORRID>
    <NOOFACTIONS></NOOFACTIONS>
    <RECDATE></RECDATE>
    <RECTIME></RECTIME>
    <ORG>UKHO</ORG>
    <ACTIONITEMS>
    </ACTIONITEMS>
    </IM_MATINFO>
    </Z_ADDS_MAT_INFO>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

If I remove the .asmx extension from the path I get a 200 response. I don't think its from this mapping but a default on that endpoint I already have in place. If I replace the .asmx I get a 404. When I leave the .asmx on the path is it treated as a file request & is actually looking for a file named "z_adds_mat_info.asmx"
